# Using Property to set value of .Net HTML Server Control

Tags: c#, html, properties

Are there any drawbacks with using a property to get or set a field on a .Net HTML server control?

**HTML**

```
<span id="aSpan" runat="server"></span>
```

**C#**

```
public string AProperty 
{
  get {
    return aSpan.InnerHtml;
  }

  set {
    aSpan.InnerHtml = value;   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it can be a great solution to use properties to set and get control values (not specifically for HtmlControls only). I have used them this way many times while using the [Model View Presenter (MVP) pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649571.aspx).

Here is an example of the MVP pattern

**Model:**

```
public interface IPresentationModel
{
    string AProperty { set; }
    string ATextbox { get; set; }
    event EventHandler SaveData;
    event EventHandler LoadData;
}
```

**View, Markup:**

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span id="aSpan" runat="server"></span>
        <input type="text" id="aTextbox" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

**View, Code Behind**

```
public partial class View : Page, IPresentationModel
{
    private Presenter _presenter;

    protected override void OnInitComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitComplete(e);
        _presenter = new Presenter(this);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData(this, e);
        }
    }

    public string AProperty
    {
        set
        {
            aSpan.InnerHtml = value;
        }
    }

    public string ATextbox
    {
        get
        {
            return aTextbox.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            aTextbox.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler SaveData;
    public event EventHandler LoadData;

    protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData(this, e);
        LoadData(this, e);
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class Presenter
{
    private readonly IPresentationModel _model;
    private static string _fakeService = "42";

    public Presenter(IPresentationModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
        _model.SaveData += SaveData;
        _model.LoadData += LoadData;
    }

    private void LoadData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _model.AProperty = _fakeService;
        _model.ATextbox = _fakeService;
    }

    private void SaveData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _fakeService = _model.ATextbox;
    }
}
```